# Drupal 7: Webform results->Submissions: how to add or modify columns here

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

When I click on "Results" and then "Submissions" I see the following columns:

```
#, Submitted, User, Ip address, Operations
```

Can you help me add a few columns from my form here?
                    or
If there is a way I can remove the whole page/option? (I know I can remove the hook_alter_menu() and remove the menu item but it shows the page on clicking on results tab as it is the default view)

Can you please help me in removing the whole page or modifying it?

Comment: What columns do you want to add and why? Or why do you want to remove the whole page?  Do you not want your users to be able to see the Submission results?  Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the webform module uses the Drupal API really well. So there is a theme function that (webform_theme) that you might use for your process.

Inside this hook_theme() implementation you find and associated array with these two keys:

```
'webform_results_submissions_header' => array(
  'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
  'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
),
'webform_results_submissions' => array(
  'render element' => 'element',
  'template' => 'templates/webform-results-submissions',
  'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
),
```

All you have to do now is provide your own implementations for the header and rows using your own hook_theme and you are done.